# mysqlbinlog: unknown variable ssl_key or ssl_cert or ssl_ca

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, ssl, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to recover binlog from a remote server using `mysqlbinlog` client program, however it appears that `mysqlbinlog` doesn't recognize the SSL options that's required to establish SSL connect to MySQL version 5.5 server, which is set to require X509.

Any other ways to get `mysqlbinlog` to connect?

Update: I've noticed this bug report from MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74864

And I've tried use `--loose` prefix for the 3 SSL options to connect. Still don't work.

Update: I am running Google Cloud SQL (a hosted version of MySQL 5.5, potentially tweaked by Google, running in Google Cloud), no other access except using MySQL client and via Google Cloud Dashboard to tweak only a few limited parameters.

This is in fact the same limitation for RDS in Amazon Cloud (AWS). The differences is that RDS have option to select MySQL minor versions whereas Google Cloud SQL doesn't allow you to choose a minor version, only 5.5 or 5.6 are available.

Answer (score 1):

## [**BOTTOM OF THE BUG REPORT YOU REFERENCED**](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74864)

> [21 Jan 16:44] David Moss
>
> Thanks for your feedback. This was fixed in version 5.7.3, and the following text was added to the 5.7.3 release notes: Previous versions of mysqlbinlog did not correctly accept the ssl-ca option in an option file. This fix ensures that this option can be correctly used. In earlier versions a work around is to use the loose-ssl-ca option.
>
> [19 Feb 16:08] David Moss
>
> Posted by developer:
>
> This was covered in the release notes. Closing.
>
> [27 Feb 9:02] Christoph Mitasch
>
> will this also be fixed for the 5.6.X release?

## **MySQL 5.6 Documentation**

The `--ssl-crl` and `--ssl-crlpath` variables were first introduced for mysqlbinlog in MySQL 5.6.3. Once MySQL 5.6 went GA, those options were not meant to be used at all. How did I know ? Look at the [***list of options for mysqlbinlog***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) (Table 4.16). They appear in the list between [`--socket`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_socket) and [`--start-datetime=datetime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_start-datetime) *BUT THEY HAVE NO HYPERLINKS !!!*

## [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html)

Here is something else to consider: [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) is not a client program. It is a utility program. In mysql, client programs require logging into mysqld with a username and password.

If you look at the [list of MySQL Client Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-client.html), please note that [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) is not there because it is a utility. You can see [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) among the [list of MySQL Administrative and Utility Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-admin-utils.html).

If you are using an option file, [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) can never respond to the options under the `[client]` group header. Why ? According to the [Options File Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html):

> The [client] option group is read by all client programs (but not by mysqld). This enables you to specify options that apply to all clients. For example, [client] is the perfect group to use to specify the password that you use to connect to the server. (But make sure that the option file is readable and writable only by yourself, so that other people cannot find out your password.) Be sure not to put an option in the [client] group unless it is recognized by all client programs that you use. ***Programs that do not understand the option quit after displaying an error message if you try to run them***.

## SUGGESTION

I don't know if you will encounter the bug with my suggestion, but here it goes ...

If you are using an option file, make the header use `[mysqlbinlog]` instead of `[client]`. As a utility, I know `[mysqlhotcopy]` can be used as a group header. Please try out `[mysqlbinlog]` as a group header and see if it helps.

## ADDITIONAL OBSERVATION

Since you are connecting to DB Server running MySQL 5.5, its mysqld will never understand `--ssl-crl` and `--ssl-crlpath` variables because they belong to MySQL 5.6.3. I guess this means you were connecting from a MySQL 5.6 machine using the mysqlbinlog for MySQL 5.6. You will not need to specify any SSL connection options if you are remote connecting for binlgogs

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. And no, I am using MySQL 5.5 in Google Hosted Cloud SQL VM - which means **no access or control** over majority of the server side configurations and the only way to get to our data is via MySQL client programs, no utility programs can be run on the hosted Cloud SQL VM. Same thing with AWS RDS.

Comment: unfortunately upgrading to MySQL 5.7 is **NOT** an option here - I think you would understand why upgrading production databse to a new non-production-ready version 5.7 is a **bad** idea being a professional DBA. So this is not the solution - it seems that there is no solution for MySQL 5.5 at all.

Comment: Please look over my answer again. I never once suggested upgrading to 5.7. I just quoted the bug report. I simply stated 5.5 and 5.6 cannot do SSL properly. Your best shot is mysqlbinlog without any SSL options because THERE ARE NO COMMAND LINE SSL OPTIONS FOR mysqlbinlog : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Comment: That's not an option either. All production database in our Google Cloud SQL is strictly enforcing  `REQUIRE X509` for accessing data. If you are not  suggesting 5.7 then you should not put that bug report section front and center as the first section of your answer, as it's irrelevant.

Comment: I just put in the front and center of my answer because you already had this info in your possession since you supplied the bug report. It is very relevant because it is an established fact (from the bug report) that mysqbinlog in MySQL 5.5./5.6 GA does not work. If you trying to recover a binlog from a remote server and the framework is private (like Amazon RDS) you may have to contact Google on this one. Since you asked `Any other ways to get mysqlbinlog to connect?`, No is the only viable answer until MySQL 5.7 goes GA and Google adopts its usage. I am sorry I could not help any more.

Comment: I am already aware of the future availability of a solution in 5.7, which is why I linked to that bug report. Thank you for validating my discoveries.